# git bash shell on Windows “Your edited hunk does not apply” (continued)

Tags: git, shell, interactive, git-add

Not too long ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917746/git-bash-shell-on-windows-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply?noredirect=1#comment71040215_41917746). I received an answer, but it did not solve the issue I was having, so I was advised to create a new question with more detail.

Just to reiterate, I am getting an error when trying to manually edit a hunk in the Git bash shell on Windows, when using `git add -p` (specifically, I press `e` when prompted by the interactive command). This opens an edit file for the hunk in Notepad++ (my default .txt editor). Even **without making any changes** to this file, I am given the error:

> Your edited hunk does not apply

---

As a minimal example, I have created a repo, value of `git config core.autocrlf` is `false` (I've also tried the following with value set to `true`). I have a .txt file (`foobar.txt`), I write `foo` in it, and commit my changes. Then I change the contents of the file to:

```
foo 
bar
```

and then close the file. I then do `git add -p foobar`, and am prompted (not sure why the diff didn't work out cleanly in this case, but it generally does work for me):

```
diff --git a/foobar b/foobar
index 1910281..a907ec3 100644
--- a/foobar
+++ b/foobar
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-foo
\ No newline at end of file
+foo
+bar
\ No newline at end of file
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

to which I answer `e`. Again, without making any changes I get the error:

```
error: patch failed: foobar:1
error: foobar: patch does not apply
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?
```

---

Of course, I have also tried making changes to the manual hunk edit file; for example, the edit file will initially look like:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-foo
\ No newline at end of file
+foo
+bar
\ No newline at end of file
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
#
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be
# marked for staging. If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given
# an opportunity to edit again. If all lines of the hunk are removed,
# then the edit is aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

A sample edit would be:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -1 +1,1 @@
-foo
\ No newline at end of file
+foo
\ No newline at end of file
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
#
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be
# marked for staging. If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given
# an opportunity to edit again. If all lines of the hunk are removed,
# then the edit is aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

---

Another interesting point is that I have a developer's release of Windows, which allows me to use "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows". Using `git add -p` through this utility, and then trying to manually edit hunks, will work... so my question is, why does it not work on Git bash shell for me...?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem; I have core.autocrlf set to true, and am using Notepad++ as my editor.

I have all whitespace made visible, and noticed that in the # comments above and below the hunk, added by Git, use LF, but the hunk itself uses CR-LF. So I applied Edit->EOL Conversion->Windows Format. I could then apply the hunk, with or without edits.

Answer (score 1):

> Even without making any changes to this file, I am given the error:
>
> ```
> Your edited hunk does not apply
> ```

That error might be less frequent with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018).
Before that, "`git add -p`" has been lazy in coalescing split patches before passing the result to underlying "git apply", leading to corner case bugs; the logic to prepare the patch to be applied after hunk selections has been tightened.

See [commit 3a8522f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a8522f41ff45b16e06888d2b164252c9aeeaa03), [commit b3e0fcf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3e0fcfe429204ccdf1f6977c55127171d65a8e5), [commit 2b8ea7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b8ea7f3c7d8dfd4f1eddaef6688b51f8106767e) (05 Mar 2018), [commit fecc6f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fecc6f3a6862c55dee0e9a2390acaf4b23991fef), [commit 23fea4c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23fea4c240218d519da01e6d2d64264084a7334c), [commit 902f414](https://github.com/git/git/commit/902f414a72b29ca9c6c575faf29cc2b0b8b4fe1c) (01 Mar 2018), and [commit 11489a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11489a6539b8840ae18b9a5c7e6dd602e8f28209), [commit e4d671c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4d671c6a686ba48f9f987fdabad0eeb49759199), [commit 492e60c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/492e60c82456b228a24ff0021e6accee946b7a1c) (19 Feb 2018) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 436d18f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/436d18f2d00b61bea44be2f8d35a437172132873), 14 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `add -p`: fix counting when splitting and coalescing
>
> When a file has no trailing new line at the end diff records this by
>   appending "`\ No newline at end of file`" below the last line of the
>   file.
>   This line should not be counted in the hunk header.
>
> Fix the splitting and coalescing code to count files without a trailing new line properly and change one of the tests to test splitting without a
>   trailing new line.

---

Update Q1 2020: [Git 2.25 will rewrite the `git-add--interactive.perl` script in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382252/6309). That will change and fix the hunk split management.